# hightcharts: change standard position of tooltip AND shadow (hover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip, shadow

please have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/zb443xj9/

The bubble is drawed higher by the radius. 
Therefore method "drawPoints" is changed as followed (because this "changing feature" is not implemented in the framework):

```
    (function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.bubble.prototype, 'drawPoints', function (p) {
        var series = this;
        H.each(series.points, function (point, i) {
            point.shapeArgs.y -= point.shapeArgs.r; //moved up by radius
        });

        p.call(this);
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

If you hover over the bubble you see, that the shadow and the tooltip **still** orientate on the **"old" center**. 
Does anybody know how the method for drawing the shadow and tooltip is named?

I'd love to **overwrite these two methods** as well.
I hoped the are called something like "drawShadow" and "drawTooltip" but unfortunately not.

Thanks!

Comment: This shadow (halo) is in series object, rendered as path dynamically so you need to wrap halo function as well (haloPath).

Comment: perfect! I simply copy and the paste the wrapper function and replace "drawPoints" through "halo"! What about the tooltip? Do you also know this function name?

Comment: What do you mean with **"haloPath"** @SebastianBochan ? `...H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.bubble.prototype, 'haloPath', function (p) {...` has no impact.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap haloPath method in point option. Then overwrite "this" object inside point.

```
H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'haloPath', function (proceed) {

                if(this.oldY === UNDEFINED) {
                    this.oldY = this.plotY;
                    this.plotY -= (this.shapeArgs.r);
                }

                return proceed.apply(this, 

Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
});

H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'getAnchor', function (proceed, points, mouseEvent) {
        var ret,
        chart = this.chart,
            inverted = chart.inverted,
            plotTop = chart.plotTop,
            plotLeft = chart.plotLeft,
            plotX = 0,
            plotY = 0,
            yAxis,
            xAxis;

        points = splat(points);

        // Pie uses a special tooltipPos
        ret = points[0].tooltipPos;

        // When tooltip follows mouse, relate the position to the mouse
        if (this.followPointer && mouseEvent) {
            if (mouseEvent.chartX === UNDEFINED) {
                mouseEvent = chart.pointer.normalize(mouseEvent);
            }
            ret = [
            mouseEvent.chartX - chart.plotLeft,
            mouseEvent.chartY - plotTop];
        }
        // When shared, use the average position
        if (!ret) {
            each(points, function (point) {
                yAxis = point.series.yAxis;
                xAxis = point.series.xAxis;
                plotX += point.plotX + (!inverted && xAxis ? xAxis.left - plotLeft : 0);
                plotY += (point.plotLow ? (point.plotLow + point.plotHigh) / 2 : point.plotY) + (!inverted && yAxis ? yAxis.top - plotTop : 0); // #1151
            });

            plotX /= points.length;
            plotY /= points.length;

            ret = [
            inverted ? chart.plotWidth - plotY : plotX,
            this.shared && !inverted && points.length > 1 && mouseEvent ? mouseEvent.chartY - plotTop : // place shared tooltip next to the mouse (#424)
            inverted ? chart.plotHeight - plotX : plotY];
        }

        if(points[0].oldY === UNDEFINED) {
            ret[1] -= points[0].shapeArgs.r;
        }

        return map(ret, mathRound);
    });
```

EDIT:
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zb443xj9/6/

Comment: But this only works if I hover 2 times over a bubble. The first time I hover, the tooltip is on its original centered postion. After I move mouse to another bubble and return to this bubble THEN the tooltip gets shifted up by radius. You see that @SebastianBochan ? perhaps we have to change the if branch somehow?

Comment: But where you would like to have a tooltip, inside center "new moved bubble"?

Comment: If you hover the first time it is too "deep". If tooltip orientates on the center of "the new moved bubble" it would be perfect! The position of the second hover is great as well. Important is that there it should not render at a different position on the first and second hover.

Comment: You need to wrap getAnchor function for tooltip, see my updated demo